# Automatically Change Sound Output Device When Plugging in Headphones

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I'm on a Mid-2009 MBP. I use an amplifier with an internal USB sound card to listen to music. That's ok for most times, but sometimes I like to listen to music with headphones plugged directly into the MBP, not into the amplifier.

Is it possible to make the MBP change the sound output device automatically to Headphone Jacket when I plug them in, even when a sound device other than the internal speakers is in use?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to do this automatically, but [SoundSource](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) from Rogue Amoeba makes it very quick to switch inputs.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not ML ready. Besides, Alt-Click on the volume menubar item offers you a similar menu